# PHP Serialized Data output inside foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, foreach

I've been stuck on this for like 2 days, and I know it's much more simpler than I think it is..

I have a foreach loop that goes like this.

```
foreach($appointments as $appointment){
  
  $list = $appointment['techs']

}
```

The $appointment['techs']; comes out of the database like this.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:2:"12";}
```

My question is, how to I get loop through appointments and then show the users that are assigned to each appointment...

The desired output should look like this,

```
{ resource : 1, event : 1},{ resource : 12, event : 1}
```

I've literally tried everything! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have determined that you have a serialized string. Have you tried unserializing it and then using the array to get the output you want?

Comment: _“I've literally tried everything!”_ - please STOP stating stuff like this. First of all, you _obviously_ haven’t, and second, this is not helpful at all. _Show us_ what exactly you tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't want to clutter up my question with all my mistakes, are you saying that the StackOverflow Community would prefer I do that, or is it something that you personally prefer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: _“Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.”_, _“Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [];
$string = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:2:"12";}';
$arr = (unserialize($string));

foreach ($arr as $item){
    array_push($array, json_encode(['resource'=> $item, 'event'=>1]));
}

$i = 0;
$numItems = count($array);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (++$i === $numItems) {
        echo $item;
    }
    else{
        echo $item.',';
    }
}
// Output: {"resource":"1","event":1},{"resource":"12","event":1}
```

Comment: This is how it's coming out...
["{\"resource\":\"1\",\"event\":1}","{\"resource\":\"12\",\"event\":1}"]["{\"resource\":\"1\",\"event\":1}","{\"resource\":\"12\",\"event\":1}"]["{\"resource\":\"1\",\"event\":1}","{\"resource\":\"12\",\"event\":1}"

how I can I get like this.

{ resource : 1, event : 1},{ resource : 12, event : 1},{ resource : 1, event : 1},{ resource : 12, event : 1},{ resource : 1, event : 1},{ resource : 12, event : 1},

Comment: So the output is actually inside the appointments loop.

I'm getting this back

"{\"resource\":\"1\",\"event\":1}","{\"resource\":\"12\",\"event\":1}"] for each appointment.

How can I get it to output without the [] and the \ slashes?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP command unserialize it's what you are looking for.

```
foreach($appointments as $appointment){
  
  $list = unserialize($appointment['techs']);

}
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thank you for your reply, but I'm trying to foreach the serialized data inside of the foreach and output it like this.....

{ resource : 1, event : 1},{ resource : 12, event : 1}